# How generic is K,V?

Tags: java, generics

If I define a `Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K, V>()` why can't I do something like:

`map.put(new MyKey<CustomObject>(), new SomeOtherObject<CustomObject>());`

But if I do it via another method it works i.e.:

```
add(new MyKey<CustomObject>(), new SomeOtherObject<CustomObject>());  

public <K, V> void add(K k, V v){  
        Map<K, V> threadLocalMap = new HashMap<K, V>();  
        threadLocalMap.put(k, v);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare the types used in your map:

```
Map<MyKey,SomeOtherObject> map = new HashMap<MyKey, SomeOtherObject>();
map.put(new MyKey<CustomObject>(), new SomeOtherObject<CustomObject>());
```

In your second example, the `add` method is generic, so when you call it, K and V are replaced by the actual type used in the calling code.

**EDIT**

You seem to misunderstand the meaning of `Map<K, V>`. K and V don't have any specific meaning, they just show that you can "parameterize" the map to only accept a certain type of key and a certain type of value. But it is your responsibility to define those types.

In your first example, you want to use `MyKey` as the type for the keys (the `K`) and `SomeOtherObject` for the values (the `V`). So you need to create a specific map for those types: `Map<MyKey,SomeOtherObject> map = new HashMap<MyKey, SomeOtherObject>();`.

You can't simply write `Map<K, V>` because K and V don't mean anything to the compiler (unless you have create a class called K and a class called V, but I assume you haven't).

In your second example, you use a generic method which takes two parameters of type K and V. When the method is called, the K and the V are replace by the actual types received, so the code in your example is transformed to something very similar to the code at the top of my answer.

I hope this clarifies things. I suggest that you spend time reading a tutorial on generics and look at concrete examples.

Comment: So you are saying it is a workarround replacing with `K` and `V`?

Comment: Why do I need to use the "helper" method here?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works : the class is generic but the instance has to be specific.

You specify the classes on which your map is usable at instanciation :

```
Map<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass> myMap = new HashMap<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass>();
```

If you'd want a fully generic instance, you'd use this :

```
Map myMap = new HashMap();
```

That is... no "generics".

Comment: In you're working code, you're just creating the instance as I describe, so there's no reason for it not to work, you just did it in a parameterized way but as you're not using a yet created map, it's near useless : you can't apply it on a yet existing parameterized map.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, the instance has to be specific as to what K and V are (this is the point of Generics - if you wanted to be able to add whatever you want to it, you just use a `Map` with no generics, or `Map<Object, Object>`). What you can do however to be able to add multiple custom classes is have them all extend a base class and have the Map be a `Map<MyKeyBaseClass, MyValueBaseClass>`. If either the key or the value can be anything, just use `Object` instead. You might find it easier if you consider that the purpose of generics is actually to narrow the scope of objects you accept, not widen it.

Edit: It seems you're having some difficulties with the basic principles of generics, I would recommend reading the [Java tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).